# Get value from select field and compare against database

Tags: php, laravel

**What I'm needing:**

Using the following DB column `clay_plan_type`

```
+----+------------------+
| id | clay_plan_type   |
+----+------------------+
|  5 | Single Shooter   |
|  6 | Lunch Sponsor    |
|  7 | Beverage Sponsor |
+----+------------------+
```

I want to disable the select options in my form if the value of my select field matches the value in `clay_plan_type`

**View example:**

```
@if ($sponsortype === "Beverage Sponsor")
<option value="" disabled>Beverage Sponsor: SOLD OUT</option>
@else
<option value="Beverage Sponsor">Beverage Sponsor: $250</option>
@endif
etc...
```

**Controller Example:**

```
$sponsortype = DB::table('clay_shoots')->select('clay_plan_type')->get();
return view('clayshoot.sponsorform',compact('sponsortype'));
```

When I `dd($sponsortype);` I get the following:

```
Collection {#855 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => {#801 ▼
      +"clay_plan_type": "Single Shooter"
    }
    1 => {#802 ▼
      +"clay_plan_type": "Lunch Sponsor"
    }
    2 => {#803 ▼
      +"clay_plan_type": "Beverage Sponsor"
    }
  ]
}
```

I get no errors when running the `if statement` in the view, but I don't get the correct results. It acts as the `if statement is not there.

So I try adding `$sponsortype->clay_plan_type` and I get the error:

> Property [clay_plan_type] does not exist on this collection instance.

If I run in a `foreach loop` this works in the View but I get multiple repeats of the same item in the select field. (See below image)

```
@foreach($sponsortype as $st)
  @if ($st->clay_plan_type == "Beverage Sponsor" )
    YUP
  @else
    NOPE
  @endif
@endforeach
// OUTPUT: NOPE NOPE YUP ("Beverage Sponsor" is the last record in the table)
```

[image]
Hope I'm explaining this in a way you understand. If you need more info, please let me know. Any help in figuring this out would be appreciated.

Comment: `$sponsortype` is a collection so you have to iterate over it in the `@foreach` as you did on the last example. Everything seems to be working fine. You should put `<input>` as `YUP` and `NOPE` and it will work. What is the problem here?

Comment: I have 4 plans: Bev, Breakfast, Lunch and Singles. I'll have up to 24 Singles in that `clay_plan_type` column and when I loop it I'll end up getting 24 Bev, Breakfast and Lunch options in my select filed. That's my problem.

Comment: Not sure whether I understand. Can you show the content of the `clay_plan_type`?

Comment: @DamianDziaduch the content is whats in the database and the die dump.

Comment: @DamianDziaduch I added an image of the foreach loop on the Beverage Sponsor option filed to help show you my predicament.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `contains` collection method and pass a key / value pair.

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-contains):

> You may also pass a key / value pair to the contains method, which
>   will determine if the given pair exists in the collection:

```
$collection = collect([
    ['product' => 'Desk', 'price' => 200],
    ['product' => 'Chair', 'price' => 100],
]);

$collection->contains('product', 'Bookcase');

// false
```

In your case:

```
@if ($sponsortype->contains("clay_plan_type", "Beverage Sponsor"))
    <option value="" disabled>Beverage Sponsor: SOLD OUT</option>
@else
    <option value="Beverage Sponsor">Beverage Sponsor: $250</option>
@endif
```

Comment: That worked perfect without a `foreach loop`. Exactly what I was needing! Thanks!